# Animate lines every 2 seconds, Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, jquery-animate

I'm programming a chart that puts a line on the numbers 0, 10, 20(form the array) etc, until the maximum of the array. this works but the lines pop up at the same time, but i want them to pop up 1 sec after each other, starting at 0, a second later on 10, a sec later on 20 etc.

I did some research and i know i need to do do it with the FuncAnimation from matplotlib. and a function over what needs to be popping up. but i can't get it to work.

i would really love your help!

here is some of my code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import gc
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

#reading my files
#putting data in array called array

#start plotting
array = array - np.nanmin(array)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    fig.set_size_inches((fileObject.numberOfColumnsInArray + 1) / 2 + 1, (fileObject.numberOfRowsInArray + 1) / 2)
    
    X_Major_ticks = np.arange(1, fileObject.numberOfColumnsInArray + 1)
    X_Minor_ticks = np.arange(1.5, fileObject.numberOfColumnsInArray)
    Y_Major_ticks = np.arange(1, fileObject.numberOfRowsInArray + 1)
    Y_Minor_ticks = np.arange(1.5, fileObject.numberOfRowsInArray)
    ax.set_xticks(X_Major_ticks)
    ax.set_xticks(X_Minor_ticks, minor=True)
    ax.set_yticks(Y_Major_ticks)
    ax.set_yticks(Y_Minor_ticks, minor=True)

    ax.grid(which='minor', alpha=1, color='black', linewidth=1)
    ax.grid(which='major', alpha=0, color='black', linewidth=0.6)
    
    ax.set_xlim(0.5, fileObject.numberOfColumnsInArray + .5)
    ax.set_ylim(0.5, fileObject.numberOfRowsInArray + .5)
    
    pos = plt.imshow(array, extent=[.5, fileObject.numberOfColumnsInArray + .5, fileObject.numberOfRowsInArray + .5, .5], cmap=reverse_colourmap(new_cmap), alpha=1)
    plt.clim(0,60)
    plt.grid(which='both', linestyle='--')    

#        for i in range(fileObject.numberOfColumnsInArray):
#            for j in range(fileObject.numberOfRowsInArray):
#                if ~np.isnan(array[j, i]):
#                    ax.text(i+1, j+1, int(array[j, i]), ha='center', va='center')

    for i in range(fileObject.numberOfColumnsInArray-1):
        for j in range(fileObject.numberOfRowsInArray):
            if abs(array[j, i] - array[j, i+1]) >= blockCutOff:
                ax.plot([i+1.5,i+1.5], [j+.5,j+1.5], linewidth=4.5,linestyle=':',color='#FF0000') 
                       
    for i in range(fileObject.numberOfColumnsInArray):
        for j in range(fileObject.numberOfRowsInArray-1):
            if abs(array[j, i] - array[j+1, i]) >= blockCutOff:
                ax.plot([i+.5,i+1.5], [j+1.5,j+1.5], linewidth=4.5, linestyle=':',color='#FF0000')
                     
 ##this part makes the lines on 0 10 20 etc. i want to put tose liens apart every 1 or 2 sec.!!!
 # i tried to start a function here but without results.
 #def animate(a):
    for i in range(fileObject.numberOfColumnsInArray):
        for j in range(fileObject.numberOfRowsInArray-1):
            while array[j, i] in range(int(np.nanmin(array)),int(np.nanmax(array)), Wavelinetime):
                ax.plot([i+.5,i+1.5], [j+1.5,j+1.5], linewidth=3, linestyle='-',color='#000000')
                break
    
    #with this i want to animate and call on the function called animate
    #ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=3000)     
    ax.set_title(deflectionTableFile.rsplit ('\\')[-1].rsplit ('_')[0] + ': ' + deflectionTableFile.rsplit ('\\')[-1].rsplit ('_')[5] + ' wave ' + str(iWaveLabel))                  
    plt.gca().invert_yaxis()    
    plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
    
    cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([.85, 0.15, 0.05, 0.7])
    cbar = fig.colorbar(pos, cax=cbar_ax, extend='max', ticks=range(0,61,5))
    cbar.minorticks_on()
    cbar.ax.set_title('ms')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used plt.pause instead of sleep and it works!

Answer (score 0):

The most basic answer to this question would be the use of Python's time  library's [`sleep()` function](https://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-time-sleep-pause-wait-sleep-stop-your-code/).

```
for i in range(fileObject.numberOfColumnsInArray):
    for j in range(fileObject.numberOfRowsInArray-1):
        while array[j, i] in range(int(np.nanmin(array)),int(np.nanmax(array)), Wavelinetime):
            ax.plot([i+.5,i+1.5], [j+1.5,j+1.5], linewidth=3, linestyle='-',color='#000000')
            # do nothing for x number of seconds e.g. 1
            time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: if i place a print function(to check if it the sleeping actually waits) before the sleep function.  The output that i get isthat the print function is printed every second but the figure does not plot the lines every second, it halts until everything is printed and still plots everything simultaniously. any idea what the cause of this is? cuz the function is working on the part of the code just fine just not for the plotting part.